# Google-chart not working in PHP-Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I am trying to introduce google charts (bar chart: day vs duration) on php - mysql db.
The below code throws an error "**Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource**"

The sql query is fine as i have ran the same in db.

Need to know the mistake in below code.

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("x.x.x.x","aaaa","bbbbb") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysql_select_db("cat", $con); 

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT 
day_info as 'Day',
Duration as 'Minutes'
from cat
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 ASC
LIMIT 7");

/*
---------------------------
example data: Table (Chart)
--------------------------
Day     Minutes
Sep-21  8.18
Sep-22  9.21
Sep-23  9.46
Sep-24  8.32
Sep-25  8.27
Sep-26  7.39
Sep-27  5.12
*/

$rows = array();
$flag = true;
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

array('label' => 'Day', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => 'Minutes', 'type' => 'number')

);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
$temp = array();
$temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Day']); 
$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Minutes']); 
$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
//echo $jsonTable;
?>

<html>
<head>
<!--Load the Ajax API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

// Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
var options = {
title: 'Day Wise Minutes',
is3D: 'true',
width: 800,
height: 600
};
// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
// Do not forget to check your div ID
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not a duplicate question, as I did not mention the db name in any quotation

Comment: did you try using double quotes? as in --> `as "Day"` and `as "Minutes"` -- or just remove all together, so long as there are no spaces